# AWS Fargate has max run time of 120 seconds?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I thought one reason to use AWS Fargate over Lambda is because it has not its limits, like max runtime (and others). However, today I discovered that the parameter`stopTimeout` which is by default set to `30s` while its maximum is `120s`. See AWS documentation for [Task definition parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html).

Am I misunderstanding this `stopTimeout` parameter? I would like to run a task that might take 10-20 min. If I do indeed misunderstand something, what does this parameter mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If I do indeed misunderstand something, what does this parameter mean?

Yes, you are misunderstand the parameter. Your task can **run for as long as you want**. However, sometimes you will want to stop it, or autoscaling group will want to do it due to health check failure, it can get stuck. The `stopTimeout` determines how long ECS will wait before forcefully killing the task if it's stuck, and does not stop on its own.

The [ECS Task lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-lifecycle.html) explains it more into detail:

> **STOPPING**

> This is a transition state where Amazon ECS is waiting on the container agent to take further action.

> For Linux containers, the container agent will send the SIGTERM signal to notify the application needs to finish and shut down, and then the sends a SIGKILL after waiting the StopTimeout duration set in the task definition.